# Rcpp -- could not find function "main"

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm learning the C++ function coded in Rcpp. Below is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;

// [[Rcpp::export]]

int addition (int a, int b) { 
  
  int r;
  r = a + b;
  return r;
}


int main () {
  int z;
  z = addition(3, 5);
  cout << "The result is " << z;
}

/*** R
main()
*/
```

But when I sourceCpp, I got the error *"Error in main() : could not find function "main" "*.

I do not know why the compiler cannot see my defined main function.

Comment: First you do not need the `main` function. Also you have to export the cpp function that you want to use into R. ie `// [[Rcpp::export]]` should be immediately before the function that you want to export. It seems you are interested in using the `addition` function. Delete everything from `int main(){...}` then within the r code chunk, instead of having `main()` have `addition(3, 5)`

Comment: @Alison:  Thanks for your interest in Rcpp.  You would likely benefit from reading the gentle-yet-comprehensive _Introduction to Rcpp_ that is [both a vignette in the package](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-introduction.pdf) and a published paper in [_The American Statistician_](https://doi.org/10.1080/00031305.2017.1375990).

Comment: @Onyambu, thanks for your reply, but I don't think deleting the main() is what I intended. My intention is to call a pre-defined function "addition" then call this function within the main function, meanwhile print out the result calcuated using the addition function.

Comment: @ Dirk Eddelbuettel Thanks for your kind reference! But after browsing through the whole paper, I didn't notice mentioning of call a pre-defined function within main() function or another function. Could you please give a more targeted reference? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Alison If you intend to do everything in C++ then whats the reason for R? Note that `addition` is available, just do `addition(2,3)` in R. anyway, as I earlier said, you need to export the function to be visible in R. right now only the function `addition` is exported. and that is the only one visible in R.

Comment: @Onyambu Thanks! Do you have any good books to recommend for understanding the big picture or the role of Rcpp. I have read advanced R Wickham, but did not notice the relevant idea.

Comment: The idea is to accelerate R. There are many books/materials written about Rcpp. NOte that the RCPP author himself, Dirk Eddelbuettel commented on your post and gave you links that you can use to learn Rcpp.